# Looping and breaking a looped task in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I created a loop in discord.py that runs when someone types the command '!loop true' and am having some troubles stopping the loop when a user types '!loop false'. Here is my code so far:

```
@client.command(hidden=True)
async def theloop(ctx,state):
    if state=='true' or state=='t':
        while True:
           #do something

@client.command()
async def loop(ctx,state):
    client.loop.create_task(theloop(ctx,state))
```

Comment: ``if state=='true' or state=='t':`` your using true as a string here, just use True as a bool value instead

Comment: what why? @thenullptr thats the if statement not the while loop. this has to take input from a user in discord in the form of a string. thats why its 'true' or 't'

Comment: did you figure this out? I would take a look at the `Cog` framework. I can add more if you're still stuck